# VB 2010 - Getting all links associated with a website in a Listbox

Tags: html, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, http

So i am making a program that would prompt the user to enter a URL and the program analyzes it, and gives you all the files/links associated with the website, kind of like when you use live HTTP headers (you get all the link to images).
so if the website is google.com it would list this -> 
`www.google.com`
`www.google.com/banner.jpg`
`www.google.com/file.js
www.google.com/news.doc`

for example :
1) the user enters the website and starts analyzing
2) the program lists all the website files
3) data outputted in a listbox

i am unable to do this as i dont have a theoretical code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters, you could do something like this to get the HTML and then use [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to get what you need  :

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

       Dim myurl As String = "http://www.stackoverflow.com"
       Dim wc As WebClient = New WebClient()
       Dim reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(wc.OpenRead(myurl))
       doSomethingToMyHTML(reader.ReadToEnd)

    End Sub
    Private Sub doSomethingToMyHTML(textinput As String)
         'get what you want with HTML Agility Pack
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to build is called a web crawler, in other contexts.

This site has a good explanation and some code examples:
http://www.developerfusion.com/article/84330/building-a-web-crawler/